# How do you transform probabilities from the form P[X=x] to P[X =< x]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm working on a problem that requires you to use a binomial distribution to solve the problem.

Now we want to determine x such that

```
P[X > x] =< 0.01
```

or, equivalently,

```
0.99 =< P[X=<x]
```

which is equal to

```
P[X=<x] => 0.99 (I added this part)
```

...

The following table summarizes the selection process for x:

```
x        P[X=x]                        P[X=<x]
0        (0.98)^20 = 0.668             0.668
1        20(0.02)(0.98)^19=0.272       0.940
```

I'm pretty sure I understand how they derived the formula for the inequality what I don't understand is how they derived the numbers that go into the table. Can somebody please explain this part? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
P\left(X\leq0\right) = P\left(X=0\right) = 0.668,\\
P\left(X\leq 1\right) = P\left(X=0\right) + P\left(X=1\right) 
$$
thus subbing your numbers in we find

$$
P\left(X\leq 1\right) = 0.668 + 0.272 = 0.94
$$